# 足が遠い　does it have the following meaning?

Tags: translation

Ok, so I found this phrase in regards to a profile of a character and there's a list given with his abilities and such. The first thing in that list was that it said that the character has good reflexes, followed by this: 足が遠い.
What I could understand was that, literally, his legs reach far? Does it imply that I dunno, he is flexible? I don't think it's similar to 長い, right? It sounded quite peculiar to me and I couldn't find some examples in sentences, except for this other phrase 足が遠のく which it looked similar, but it has another meaning.

Comment: 「足が遅い」の間違いじゃないですよね・・

Comment: いいえ。「遠」の漢字が書かれました。プリントの間違いかもしれないかな。。。

Comment: 「遠い」ではなく、「速い」でしょうか。

Comment: @virmaior きっとそうでしょ。字が小さけたりすると、大いにあり得る読み間違いですね。

Comment: May I ask where you found the profile of the character? It could be that his legs are just really long, and in that (manga?) he has that special characteristic.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that expression have various meanings for what I've read, It can means that "you are far (from home)", meaning that you are travelling or living abroad, maybe in a tour. It can also means that you are distant of yourself or distant of someone.

So It maybe sounds weird because it does not make any logic in our own languages, let me show you some other examples:

> 背が高い (せがたかい): (My back is tall) ► I'm tall
>
> 体が痛い (からだがいたい): My body hurts (This one is not always use in the literal way, sometimes you use it when you feel bad)

So as you can see in Japanese some expressions doesn't mean the literal translation in our languages.

Comment: プロフィールのabilityの欄に「足が遠い」って、日本語でも意味わかんないんですけど・・

Comment: 「足は体の他の部分との距離が近くない」と言う意味じゃないですか。(笑) @Chocolate